# cant connect to server with domain name only ipv6 address

Tags: networking, google-chrome

we have a server which is able to answer requests when using ipv6.
when using domain name chrome shows DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN.
nslookup works fine.

eg.
https://[aa:bb:cc:dd]/index.html works
https://mydomain/index.html does not work

what am I missing? thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] the question and copy&paste the `nslookup` command with its output and the exact URL. Re-typing or anonymizing might introduce or hide errors.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up/reconfigure the DNS record to point to that IP-address.

If you are familiar with handling DNS records then you can change it yourself, otherwise perhaps your DNS hosting company can help you.

Remember that changes in DNS can take a long time propagate. You can try the command: ipconfig /flushdns in the Windows command prompt in case it is your local computer that is holding old dns cache.

Comment: can you share what should be the format of the ipv6 address in the AAAA record value? I've tried `aa:bb:cc:dd::1` , `aa:bb:cc:dd::` and neither works. it's not allowing me to put just `aa:bb:cc:dd` or `aa:bb:cc:dd::\64`

Comment: I put the IPV6 address as shown by sites like https://www.whatismyip.com/, that works for SSH, so I'm assuming the DNS is correct, but chrome gives me the same error. Tor browser is OK with showing the page, strangely. Chrome and Firefox are not.